# What do we mean by displacement in real life?

Tags: displacement

I know, I know, reference frame and shit. But, I am asking which one are we calculating? When we are calculating we are using Euclidean Geometry. So how should we think about it in form of Spherical Geometry?
For example, there are two cities A and B. They both lie in the same longitude. So which path is the displacement, the yellow one or the blue one?[image]

Comment: Have you read this question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24662/what-is-displacement-position-relative-to-a-reference-point-or-change-of-positi?rq=1

Comment: I guess I am too stupid. I read the whole thing, but I didn't understand which path would it be......

Comment: There is no shit in physics.

Comment: You seem to have taken what I said quite literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would summarize that it is a bit the matter of convention. Quick side note: Displacement, to my mind as a condensed matter physicist, is actually the distance with respect to some reference point, so the displacement of city $A$ relative to city $B$ seems a somewhat odd quantity. You can give it a mathematical sense if you refer it to a path, that is the final displacement an object experienced when it travelled from city $A$ to city $B$ by some arbitrary path. Cf. wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(geometry)

Pedantry aside, the displacement has something to do with the geometry you imprint on your system. When you embrace $\color{blue}{\textrm{spherical geometry}}$, the displacement is the $\color{blue}{\textrm{blue line}}$ in your sketch. That is the shortest path you can take when you restrict yourself to moving along the surface of the earth.

If you had a powerful drill, you might not want to accept the metric of the sphere. In the geometry appropriate to the motion with a drill ($\color{orange}{\textrm{Euclidean geometry}}$), the $\color{orange}{\textrm{yellow line}}$ is the displacement.

So, in the end, both options are available, they correspond to different underlying geometries, and it is your description of the problem and the kind of question you want to ask that leads you to decide on a specific geometry.

Comment: Let's say I want to know the distance from  Torrens Creek (Queensland) and Kyabram (Victoria) [Yes, I did just google that, why do you ask?]. I take out the map and check the shortest path between both of them. Consider that I am from a Rich family so I have quite good equipment and same for my map. I use the scale of the map given. So the Distance I calculate will be the Yellow or Blue Path.

Comment: Blue, if the map's any good. Typically you don't have to be rich to get a good map or a ruler, but of course it won't hurt (in the US at least). The map projects a part of the sphere onto a 2d surface (the piece of paper it's on), **maintining the lengths and angles of the sphere**. That is quite reasonable, since a hiker would much rather want to know how much steps they have to walk to get to the destination, not so much how far it would be for a mole. Of course, this is only approximately true because we talk about an ideal sphere here, which the earth isn't, but I hope the point is clear.

Comment: What has been bothering me is that, if this is true, if I take the map and wrap it along a sphere, according to what you are saying, the 2D map should give the sense of direction that of a 3D globe, it should completely wrap it up with no space in between and no wrinkles.But this does not happen. It is the same reason why Greenland looks huge on a map but is so small when we see it with the help of a globe. As the slope near the poles is crazy high, the measurements differ. That's why I have been having a problem accepting that it is blue.

Comment: If you are interested in deep explanation here, you need to get acquainted with topological manifolds. In brief, it is possible to take a **part** of something that *locally* is two-dimensional (like a sphere, the 2d surface of a 3d ball) and map it onto a **part** of the two-dimensional plane (such that angles and distances are conserved), and this map is invertible, that is you can take the paper you mapped on an recover the part of the sphere you started from. This is no longer true *globally*: you cannot map the **entire** earth on a 2d surface and maintain all angles and distances.

Comment: That's also why, around the equator, you often have these squares or rectangles on a world map that become distorted if you move further away from the equator. They mean to indicate identical areas, but the nature of the projection distorts them.

Comment: If you want some entertaining intro to map projections, look into https://xkcd.com/977/ and correspondingly https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/977:_Map_Projections

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sources will check them out!

Answer (score 0):

@*Blank* you seem to be referring to distance on a map of places on the earth's surface. If things get bigger than relatively local area maps, its better to think of a geodesic along the earth's surface which is the equivalent of a "shortest distance" along the surface of a sphere.

Map making is pretty complex in practice with lots of trade-offs because things like distance, angles etc get distorted in going from curved surface to a flat plane. The way cartographers usually make local area maps with some distance scale (I think what you mean by displacement) is to tack an ellipsoid to some known reference point on the earth's surface (a benchmark). The ellipsoid is a best fit over some limited area to that piece of earth-surface. They then choose a projection method onto a plane and preserve more or less the surface distances that really exist on the actual earth's surface. So in your sketch they are usually trying to preserve the distance along the surface (blue) on the flat map.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!